# Canon Printer(Imageclass MF246dn) issues with ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing, canon, 22.04

In ubuntu 22.04, canon imageclass MF246dn printer installed automatically, but cannot print.so I download driver from canon official site but it also fails to print.is there is any way to properly install driver for canon printer in ubuntu 22.04?

[Output of systemctl status ipp-usb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTT1R.png)

[Output of lpstat -t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFENr.png)

Comment: Connected to the network or by USB?

Comment: connected to USB

Comment: Disconnect from USB. Then reconnect and give the outputs of `syatemctl status ipp-usb` and `lpstat -t`.

Comment: screenshots of outputs are attached above

Answer (score 0):

The ipp-usb.service is active. That is good. It is precisely what should happen on Ubuntu 22.04.

However, `lpstat -t` shows that the printer has noy been automatically set up by cups-browsed. This is not a disaster because it ca easily be set up manually.

- Execute `driverless`. The output is the **URI** for the printer.
- **Substitute** what you have for **URI** in the command `lpadmin -p MF246dn  -v "URI" -E -m everywhere`. Do not forget the double quotes arround what you substituted for URI.
- Test printing with `lp -d MF246dn /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: WOW !!!...its working....thanks brian_p